# Are MySQL where clauses linear. How to optimise

Tags: mysql, database, query-optimization, database-optimization

Supposing I had a product database of some 50,000 products supplying data to a back end system and a website, some are live, some are archived and some are “switched off” as far as the website is concerned (available only in back end admin for some reason).

A query for the website might look something like this:

```
SELECT name, category, price FROM products WHERE category=‘1234’
```

(Obviously extremely simplified)

Now as mentioned above I only want those which are not archived and which are toggled to display on the website.

```
SELECT name, category, price FROM products WHERE category=‘1234’ AND display=true AND archived=false
```

This obviously will work.

I am deliberately not mentioning indexes. I know that in the above examples whether my ‘category’ column is indexed or not will make a big difference to query speed, but this is not my question.

Supposing I know that about half of the 50,000 products in this database are old news, archived items, my question is:

Is:

```
SELECT name, category, price FROM products WHERE archived=false AND category=‘1234’ AND display=true
```

A faster query than the query I wrote earlier?

My thinking being that if MySQL eliminated 25,000 products from the query immediately on ‘archived=false’ before even considering which category these products have, it might be faster (assuming an index on ‘archived’ of course)

Hence my title “Is MySQL Where Clause linear” - does it eliminate rows sequentially in order in the criteria of the WHERE clause as written?

Comment: Short answer: The order of conditions doesn't matter. The optimizer will choose the one, wich it considers to be "optimal". However - the indexes matter. But - as your write - that is not your question.

Comment: Ok cool. I will stop worrying about the clause order then and just make sure everything required is indexed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other answers have said, you should create indexes to optimize, not rely on the order of terms in your WHERE clause. MySQL's optimizer knows how to reorder the terms to match the order of columns in an index. In other words, MySQL knows that `AND` is [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property).

But to answer your original question more directly: MySQL also knows how to shortcut boolean expressions.

Here's a demonstration: I filled a table with 512 rows, and set just a few rows to have `display=true`:

```
mysql> select count(*) from mytable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      512 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from mytable where display = true;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

There's no index on the `display` column for this test. So the query will do a table-scan, examining every row.

Now I query with a boolean expression using the `sleep()` function. If MySQL does not do short-cuts, it will evaluate the `sleep()` for every row, and take 512 seconds. If it does short-cuts, it will evaluate `sleep()` only for rows where the first term is true.

```
mysql> select count(*) from mytable where display = true and sleep(1);
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.01 sec)
```

Interesting - even if we reverse the order of terms, MySQL still short-cuts. Apparently, it knows to evaluate against row data before evaluating other expressions.

```
mysql> select count(*) from mytable where sleep(1) and display=true;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.01 sec)
```

Without a term for the display=true, it just waits. I'm not going to let it run the full 512 seconds, but running SHOW PROCESSLIST shows that it's going to just keep running:

```
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Id | User            | Host      | db   | Command | Time   | State                  | Info                                        |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|  9 | root            | localhost | test | Query   |     82 | User sleep             | select count(*) from mytable where sleep(1) |
| 11 | root            | localhost | NULL | Query   |      0 | starting               | show processlist                            |
+----+-----------------+-----------+------+---------+--------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: That is very interesting! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rearranging the `ANDed` components of the `WHERE` clause has no impact on performance.

Having a "composite" (multi-column) `INDEX` may be important.  And in this case, the order may be very important.

In your simple example,

```
WHERE category='1234'
  AND display=true
  AND archived=false
```

the optimal index is `INDEX(category, display, archived)` and *any ordering in the index is equally good*.

However, with

```
WHERE category > '1234'
  AND display=true
  AND archived=false
```

now the optimal index is

```
INDEX(display, archived,   -- in either order
      category)            -- range last
```

In the examples I have spelled out here, the processing goes like this:

1. Drill down the BTree containing the index to the starting point given by the `WHERE`.
2. Scan linearly forward through the index.
3. For each entry, reach over into the data's BTree to find `name, category, price`.

If, instead, you only have `INDEX(category, ...)` and `WHERE category > ...`, it will ignore the other two columns in the `INDEX`.  This makes the index less efficient -- read and grab a few rows, read but skip a few rows, etc.

`CATEGORY IN (123, 234, 345)` is a different matter.  In this case, the processing may hop through the index.  This is better than "read but skip", yet not as good as simply reading and using each entry.

The opposite of "linear" is "logarithmetic" or "quadradic" (etc).  However, these doe not apply in BTree indexes, so I don't understand where your question is headed.

Cookbook on indexing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

You can imagine the 3-column indexes and 3-part `WHEREs` discussed here as being concatenated together.  That is WHERE blah = 1234truefalse with an index on categorydisplayarchived.  Now it is just like a "single" column index being used against a single WHERE test.

If the index and the WHERE don't have the same number of columns, the discussion gets more complex.

Meanwhile, `INDEX(archived)` is virtually useless.  When a "flag" in indexed, the Optimizer usually says "Why bother looking through the index; I'll just have to bounce back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree; I may as well simply scan straight through the data (and toss rows he does not want)."  More, importantly, `INDEX(archived), INDEX(display), INDEX(category)` is not as helpful as `INDEX(archived, display, category)` *for the original query*.  Only one index is used at a time (usually).

Answer (score 1):

A table alone can be accessed in 2 ways - full table scan, scan an index - pick row ids - then scan those rows of the table. When multiple indexes are present on the table, only 1 will be used because that gives direct access to the rows on the table. Additional where condition will be evaluated when table rows are accessed.

In absence of any index - the where conditions are linear as per the cost of comparison which is much smaller than table access so it doesn't matter much (unless you have a very complex function call).

In presence of 1 index - efficiency of that index (its size, cardinality and density) determines cost. Other where conditions comparison are linear but again smaller in cost so it doesn't matter (unless you have a very complex function call).

In presence of multiple indexes - the most efficient index will be picked.

Get the plan of the SQL and that will show how it will be executed. I would generally focus on building  an efficient index for your case. For small table I won't build any index and would let the full scan happen.